# Why do I get the error "called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed" when I try to execute a query with DBI?

Tags: postgresql, perl

I'm trying to select some rows from a table (PostgreSQL) using the following code:

```
my $kadadbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$host",
    $dbuser,
    $dbpasswd
);

my $subject_nar_sel= $kadadbh->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM subject WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(id AS text),1,6) = "?";'
);

$nar=605812;
$subject_nar_sel->execute($nar);
```

But I get an error:

> called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed at ...

I get the same error when I swap the single and double quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM subject WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(id AS text),1,6) = '?';"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Think of `?` as a variable or a field name.

Answer (score 6):

You current query is testing whether `SUBSTRING(CAST(id AS text),1,6)` matches the <strike>literal string</strike> suspiciously-named quoted identifier `"?"`. So don't quote the `?`, even when the bind parameter has a string type:

```
SELECT * FROM subject WHERE SUBSTRING(CAST(id AS text),1,6) = ?
```

Comment: Furthermore, `"?"` isn't a string literal in (standard) SQL, that's a quoted identifier so the database would complain about "unknown column `?`" if you did manage to get past the `execute` call. Same solution of course but one bug was hiding another bug.